# How to suppress logging of certain E_WARNINGs in PHP?

Tags: php, unix

In my script I need to delete a file, that may or may not be there:

```
unlink($path);
```

Like the actual unlink(2), [PHP's unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) will unlink the entry, *if it is there*. If it is not, however, PHP will log the useless (to my purposes) message at E_WARNING level... I guess, this is nice for some people, but not for me :(

Programming in C, I could examine the errno and simply ignore the ENOENT in this case. What can one do in PHP — how to suppress the logging of this warning?

I'd rather not check for the file before trying to unlink it — doing so adds another filesystem-traversal for no reason other than cosmetics:

```
if (file_exists($path))
    unlink($path);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can prefix an expression with @ to suppress warnings for just that expression (e.g., @unlink($path)).

Comment: Better to handle the error than suppress it. However, PHP's error reporting settings might be useful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Yes, just use the error-suppression operator `@` in such cases. But beware of growing a habit -- this scenario is the exception, not the rule.

Comment: I agree with garlon4 and Jon, use the suppressor "@" but don't use it all the time, especially for critical code.

Comment: Garlon4, could you turn your comment into answer, so I can pick it as the one? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prefix an expression with @ to suppress warnings for just that expression (e.g., `@unlink($path);`).

Answer (score 1):

**php.ini configuratioin**

I agree with everyone who mentioned using "@" to suppress the error.

You can also change some of the settings in you php.ini file so that the error won't show up.

```
 ; Error Level Constants:
; E_ALL             - All errors and warnings (includes E_STRICT as of PHP 6.0.0)
; E_ERROR           - fatal run-time errors
; E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR  - almost fatal run-time errors
; E_WARNING         - run-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_PARSE           - compile-time parse errors
; E_NOTICE          - run-time notices (these are warnings which often result
;                     from a bug in your code, but it's possible that it was
;                     intentional (e.g., using an uninitialized variable and
;                     relying on the fact it's automatically initialized to an
;                     empty string)
; E_STRICT          - run-time notices, enable to have PHP suggest changes
;                     to your code which will ensure the best interoperability
;                     and forward compatibility of your code
; E_CORE_ERROR      - fatal errors that occur during PHP's initial startup
; E_CORE_WARNING    - warnings (non-fatal errors) that occur during PHP's
;                     initial startup
; E_COMPILE_ERROR   - fatal compile-time errors
; E_COMPILE_WARNING - compile-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_USER_ERROR      - user-generated error message
; E_USER_WARNING    - user-generated warning message
; E_USER_NOTICE     - user-generated notice message
; E_DEPRECATED      - warn about code that will not work in future versions
;                     of PHP
; E_USER_DEPRECATED - user-generated deprecation warnings
;
; Common Values:
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, except for notices)
;   E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR  (Show only errors)
;   E_ALL | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, warnings and notices including coding standards.)
; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
; Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
; http://php.net/error-reporting
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

This final line error_reporting allows you to change exactly what errors you want to show up. In your case, the `E_WARNING` error is what you are trying to avoid so I would use `E_ALL &  ~E_WARNING`.

I hope this helps.